# How can I apply where clause to the existing IEnumerable<model> for incremental filtering the record

Tags: asp.net-core, controller

I am trying to filter the record by giving where clause conditionally from  controller. I have the list of records as IEnumerable list . How can I give where condition to the IEnumerable.
Here is my code

```
    public IActionResult UniformIssueList(UniformDeliveryVM uniformDeliveryVM)
{
     var issuesList = _unitOfWork.UniformReceiptRepo.GetUniformDeliveryList(uniformDeliveryVM.FromDate, uniformDeliveryVM.ToDate);
         if (uniformDeliveryVM.DepotNo>=0)
         {
           issuesList  = issuesList.Where(d => d.DepotNo == uniformDeliveryVM.DepotNo
         }
     if (uniformDeliveryVM.DepartmentNo >=0)
         {
           issuesList  = issuesList.Where(d => d.DepartmentNo == uniformDeliveryVM.DepartmentNo
         }
          if (uniformDeliveryVM.EmployeeId >=0)
         {
           issuesList  = issuesList.Where(d => d.EmployeeId == uniformDeliveryVM.EmployeeId
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your idea is correct, you only need to add Tolist() after the Where condition.

like this:

```
if (uniformDeliveryVM.DepotNo >= 0)
            {
                issuesList = issuesList.Where(d => d.DepotNo == uniformDeliveryVM.DepotNo).ToList();
            };
            if (uniformDeliveryVM.DepartmentNo >= 0)
            {
                issuesList = issuesList.Where(d => d.DepartmentNo == uniformDeliveryVM.DepartmentNo).ToList();
            }
            if (uniformDeliveryVM.EmployeeId >= 0)
            {
                issuesList = issuesList.Where(d => d.EmployeeId == uniformDeliveryVM.EmployeeId).ToList();
            }
```

Hope this can help you.